# Video not playing in Xcode; NIL String Parameter

Tags: iphone, video, xcode4.3

Here is the code that I wrote to play a video in my Xcode project. When I run the project it crashes on me.  I get this reason: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

I've found a tutorial that works when I run it on the simulator.
I added my video to the project and updated the code accordingly. My video is in a m4v format just like the other video in the tutorial.  When I run the app with my video it still crashes and gives me the same error.  I took my video from quick time and exported it over to iTunes.  What am I doing wrong?

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>  

@interface BigBuckBunnyViewController : UIViewController {

}

-(IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "BigBuckBunnyViewController.h"

@implementation BigBuckBunnyViewController

-(IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender
{
UIButton *playButton = (UIButton *) sender; 

NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ladder rack 1 4"  
ofType:@"m4v"];
NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] 
initWithContentURL:fileURL];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self

selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)

name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification

object:moviePlayerController];

[moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(playButton.frame.origin.x, 

playButton.frame.origin.y, 

playButton.frame.size.width, 

playButton.frame.size.height)];

[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
//moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;

//moviePlayerController.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;

[moviePlayerController play];
}

- (void)moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification *)notification
{
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [notification object];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self

name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification

object:moviePlayerController];

[moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
[moviePlayerController release];
}

- (void)dealloc {
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Ok so I was able to create an html page and link the html page to my .m file in the view did load section.  I created an UIWebview and added it to my xib view.  I placed my video on a server.  This is probably a better solution, less load time.

Comment: because you set your playercontroller to nil. dont set it that way.

Comment: when you inspect your app bundle, does it contain tcniche.mp4?

Comment: Superman what should I set it to?  I tried to delete the line and run the app but I still get the same outcome.

Comment: Carl should I be looking in the info.plist for the app bundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are geting nil because the `NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ladder rack 1 4" ofType:@"m4v"];` contains spaces.
So you need to change it like:

```
NSURL   *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath] absoluteString];
```

Refer this [link](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/26589-nsurl-fileurlwithpath-problems-with-spaces-in-path.html)

Comment: ok so I changed videos and I added the absoluteString to the end of the NSURL like so.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface TipsViewController : UIViewController {

  MPMoviePlayerViewController *playerController;
}

-(IBAction)playVideo;

@end
```

.m file

```
 - (IBAction)playVideo{

 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"tcniche"  
    ofType:@"mp4"]];

 if(url != nil){

           playerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] 
    initWithContentURL:url];
           [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playerController];

           playerController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;

          [playerController.moviePlayer play]; 
 }
 else{

      NSLog(@"URL not found");

    }

 }
```

if url is null, check your file and path.

**Note**:Do the memory management stuff own :)

Comment: So I have tried multiple tutorials and everyone seems to work.  But they all set their project to nil.  I am using the latest version of Xcode and it is being deployed on iOS 6.  I still get the nil string error. I've been told to not set my code to nil. What should I set it to?  I have removed the nil before and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: better to choose ARC Enabled in your project.. and check the path.. MPMoviePlayerViewController must be a global variable..

Comment: Ok so I created a new project used your code Ramshad. I enabled ARC checked the file path to where my video is stored at and it is showing in my project folder.  How do I go about making the MPMoviePlayerViewController a global variable?

Comment: could you please send the sample app to my gmail ? id is "ramshadram90@gmail.com" .. notify me after done it.. then i can look in detail and resolve ur issue..

Comment: Here is what I ended up writing and it seems to be working. I added a UIWebView, then I added an HTML file to my project. Then I referenced the HTML file in my .m file.  I used this code in my viewDidLoad section. [videoWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle ]pathForResource:@"videohtml" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]]; I wrote this in my html file. <video width="300" height="240" controls="controls">
            <source src="http://our website" type="video/mp4">
        </video>